# Errors while fixing errors in C

Tags: c

I have one .c file and two headers. I don't have a qlue why these errors appered. I was trying to find solutions in the net but couldn't apply it to my code.

Structs.h

```
#ifndef STRUCTS_H
#define STRUCTS_H

typedef struct stream
{
    char* enc; //binary string
    int pos;
}stream;

typedef struct tag
{
    int tagClass;
    char tagConstructed;
    char tagNumber;
}tag;

#endif
```

Funcs.h Errors:

```
Error   22  error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '&'  c:\users\natasha\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\asn1\asn1\functions.c    15  1   asn1
Error   26  error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '&'  c:\users\natasha\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\asn1\asn1\functions.c    36  1   asn1
Error   21  error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '&'  c:\users\natasha\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\asn1\asn1\functions.c    15  1   asn1
Error   25  error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '&'  c:\users\natasha\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\asn1\asn1\functions.c    36  1   asn1
Error   15  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'isUniversal'    c:\users\natasha\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\asn1\asn1\functions.c    3   1   asn1
Error   18  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'isEOC'  c:\users\natasha\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\asn1\asn1\functions.c    7   1   asn1
Error   17  error C2059: syntax error : 'type'  c:\users\natasha\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\asn1\asn1\functions.c    3   1   asn1
Error   20  error C2059: syntax error : 'type'  c:\users\natasha\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\asn1\asn1\functions.c    7   1   asn1
Error   16  error C2059: syntax error : ';' c:\users\natasha\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\asn1\asn1\functions.c    3   1   asn1
Error   19  error C2059: syntax error : ';' c:\users\natasha\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\asn1\asn1\functions.c    7   1   asn1
Error   24  error C2059: syntax error : ')' c:\users\natasha\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\asn1\asn1\functions.c    15  1   asn1
Error   28  error C2059: syntax error : ')' c:\users\natasha\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\asn1\asn1\functions.c    36  1   asn1
Error   23  error C2059: syntax error : '&' c:\users\natasha\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\asn1\asn1\functions.c    15  1   asn1
Error   27  error C2059: syntax error : '&' c:\users\natasha\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\asn1\asn1\functions.c    36  1   asn1


#ifndef FUNCS_H
#define FUNCS_H

#include "Structs.h"

bool isUniversal(tag curTag);
bool isEOC(tag curTag);
char getByte(stream curStream);
void parseTag(stream & str, tag & tag);
char parseLength(stream & str);

#endif
```

Functions.c Errors:

```
Error   22  error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '&'  c:\users\natasha\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\asn1\asn1\functions.c    15  1   asn1
Error   26  error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '&'  c:\users\natasha\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\asn1\asn1\functions.c    36  1   asn1
Error   21  error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '&'  c:\users\natasha\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\asn1\asn1\functions.c    15  1   asn1
Error   25  error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '&'  c:\users\natasha\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\asn1\asn1\functions.c    36  1   asn1
Error   15  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'isUniversal'    c:\users\natasha\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\asn1\asn1\functions.c    3   1   asn1
Error   18  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'isEOC'  c:\users\natasha\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\asn1\asn1\functions.c    7   1   asn1
Error   17  error C2059: syntax error : 'type'  c:\users\natasha\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\asn1\asn1\functions.c    3   1   asn1
Error   20  error C2059: syntax error : 'type'  c:\users\natasha\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\asn1\asn1\functions.c    7   1   asn1
Error   16  error C2059: syntax error : ';' c:\users\natasha\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\asn1\asn1\functions.c    3   1   asn1
Error   19  error C2059: syntax error : ';' c:\users\natasha\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\asn1\asn1\functions.c    7   1   asn1
Error   24  error C2059: syntax error : ')' c:\users\natasha\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\asn1\asn1\functions.c    15  1   asn1
Error   28  error C2059: syntax error : ')' c:\users\natasha\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\asn1\asn1\functions.c    36  1   asn1
Error   23  error C2059: syntax error : '&' c:\users\natasha\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\asn1\asn1\functions.c    15  1   asn1
Error   27  error C2059: syntax error : '&' c:\users\natasha\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\asn1\asn1\functions.c    36  1   asn1


#include "Funcs.h"

bool isUniversal(tag curTag) {
    return curTag.tagClass == 0x00;
}

bool isEOC(tag curTag) {
    return (curTag.tagClass == 0x00) && (curTag.tagNumber == 0x00);
}

char getByte(stream curStream) {
    return curStream.enc[curStream.pos];
}

void parseTag(stream & str, tag & tag)
{
    char buf, tempNumber;
    buf = getByte(str);
    tempNumber = 0x00;
    tag.tagClass = buf >> 6;
    tag.tagConstructed = ((buf & 0x20) != 0);
    tag.tagNumber = buf & 0x1F;
    if (tag.tagNumber == 0x1F)
    {
        do
        {
            str.pos++;
            buf = getByte(str);
            tempNumber = (tempNumber << 7) | (buf & 0x7F);
        }while(buf & 0x80);

        tag.tagNumber = tempNumber;
    }
}

char parseLength(stream & str) {
    char buf, len;
    int numberOfOctets, i;
    buf = getByte(str);
    len = 0x00;
    numberOfOctets = 0;
    if (buf < 0x80) {
        len = buf; //short form
    } else { //long form
        numberOfOctets = buf & 0x7F;
        for (i = 0; i < numberOfOctets; ++i) {
            len = (len * 256) + getByte(str);
            str.pos++;
        }
    }

    return len;
}
```

Comment: C doesn't have references like C++.. `void parseLength(stream & str);` isn't valid syntax (because of the `&`).  You can use pointers instead, though.

Comment: @Dmitri, thanks! This advice helped me to cope with big part of errors. But errors in lines with bool are still present. I've tried to add <stdbool.h> but compiler can't recognize this header/

Comment: Older versions of C don't have a `bool` type, but you can use an integer type instead... C99 and up you can get `bool` by including the `stdbool.h` header.

Comment: @Dmitri, thanks a milion for your help!

Answer (score 1):

C doesn't have references like C++ does.  `void parseLength(stream & str);` is not valid syntax, due to the `&`.  You can use pointers instead, though.

For example, to convert your `parseLength()` function to use a pointer (and change the return type to match the definition), the prototype becomes:

```
char parseLength(stream *str);
```

And in the function body you'll need to dereference the pointer as needed, like this:

```
char parseLength(stream *str) {
    char buf, len;
    int numberOfOctets, i;
    buf = getByte(*str); /* use "*" to get the object from the pointer */
    len = 0x00;
    numberOfOctets = 0;
    if (buf < 0x80) {
        len = buf; //short form
    } else { //long form
        numberOfOctets = buf & 0x7F;
        for (i = 0; i < numberOfOctets; ++i) {
            len = (len * 256) + getByte(*str);
            str->pos++; /* Use "->" to access struct members from the pointer */
        }
    }

    return len;
}
```

Also, you'll need to pass an address (pointer) instead of the actual object, so you'd also need to change calls to the function from eg. `parseLength(str)` to `parseLength(&str)`.

You would of course need to make similar changes for `parseTag()` and any other code that tries to use references.

Likely some of the other functions like `getByte()` should be taking a pointer instead of the actual struct as well... for example if `getByte()` needs to modify the `pos` member of the `stream` argument it's passed such that it affects the object from the caller and not just a copy of it.

Also, `parseLength()` should probably return `int` or `size_t` instead of `char` -- `len` looks like it will need a larger range than that of `char`.